# Write excel issue when opening .xls

Tags: r, excel

the community here has been very helpful and I'm learning a ton! I wanted to ask -

Is there a reason why this code would take a .xls, save it as a .xls but then yield (please see snip) as a warning when opening?

The warning - "The files format and extension of 'file.xls' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open anyway?"

I believe it has something to do with the write_xlsx function. If I could know, I am taking a mix of .xls and .xlsx and outputting them as original file names/extension name. I would just like to be able to do either file format and not receive an error when I try and open the .xls files, the .xlsx open just fine without error. Thank you!

```
write_xlsx(x = data[,1:11], path = (paste0("bad/", files1)))
```

Comment: You are using `write_xlsx` so I would expect the extension to be `xlsx` instead of `xls` which is an older Excel format. I think this causes the warning.

Comment: `.xls` is not and will not be supported: https://github.com/ropensci/writexl/issues/11

Comment: It's true - now the weird thing is write.xlsx does what I want BUT - even though it works outside of the loop I'm attempting to use it in, when I put it my loop, it breaks the loop code